# Biblatex (BibTeX backend) - citations out of order

Tags: biblatex

I'm compiling my document using

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

The citations work fine but they are completely out of order - 8, 9, 1, 10, 7, 17 - and I don't know what causes it. The only thing before the actual document is a table of contents which does not contain any citations.

All the answers I've found come down to "use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`" which is impossible as the command is incompatible with Biblatex.

Comment: `\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`?

Comment: I've edited your question. You can roll back if I'm wrong. But you are using Biblatex with the BibTeX backend, I think. If you have that `\usepackage` line there, that's what you are doing.

Comment: I have that line without "sorting=none". Should I add that?

Comment: If you want the equivalent of `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`, yes.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!! I believe I can mark this question as answered if you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the equivalent of `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`, then you should replace

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

with

```
\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```